# Preventing interactive prompts for parameter values in scripts

Tags: powershell, syntax, parameter-passing, prompt, non-interactive

I have a script, `pingtest.ps1`, which makes the following call:

```
Start-abc -SourceIpaddress x.y.x.z -Protocol TCP -DestinationIpAddress a.c.d.e
```

During execution it prompts for the source port and destination port.

How do I avoid these interactive prompts and instead pass the values in the same script?

Comment: What cmdlet is `Start-abc` ??

Comment: i cannot think of any way to answer your code question without _seeing the actual code_ ... [*grin*]

Comment: its customized script imported as module.

Comment: Ok, but without us knowing what that script uses as parameters it is not really possible to give you sound advice on it. My guess is that is has two more mandatory parameters you need to feed it. Something like this: `Start-abc -SourceIpaddress x.y.x.z -SourcePort 123 -Protocol TCP -DestinationIpAddress a.c.d.e -DestinationPort 321`

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

Adding something like `-SourcePort 42` and `-DestinationPort 666` to your `Start-abc` call should prevent these interactive prompts (of course you must supply appropriate values in lieu of the sample values `42` and `666` used here).

To determine the exact name of these parameters and for background information, read on.

---

If invocation of a command doesn't supply arguments to all of its *mandatory* parameters (parameters that require values in order for the command to operate):

- PowerShell by design interactively *prompts* for these arguments,
- and only if you supply all required arguments (using valid values) does the command actually execute.

Note: This prompting mechanism is rarely used in practice and doesn't work with all parameter types - see [GitHub issue #4068](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4068).

---

If you simply want to ***prevent* interactive prompts at *runtime***, run your command via a new **PowerShell instance started with `-noninteractive`**:

```bash
powershell.exe -noninteractive -file C:\path\to\pingtest.ps1
```

This way your script **won't *prompt* and report an *error* instead**, which indicates the name of the (first) mandatory parameter for which no argument was provided.

**Caveat**: With default error handling in effect, script execution will still *continue*; setting `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` would prevent that.

---

If you want to ***determine at design time* which parameters are mandatory**, use 
**`Get-Command <command> -Syntax`**.

If necessary and available, supplement with `Get-Help -Detailed <command>` (or `-Full`) or `Get-Help -Parameter <parameterName> <command>` to learn specifics about the parameters.
Note, however, that custom scripts and functions may not have help information associated with them.

PowerShell's **syntax diagrams**, documented in the conceptual [about_Command_Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax) help topic, aren't the easiest to decipher, but they do tell you which parameters are mandatory.

Using the `Get-Item` cmdlet as an example:

```bash
PS> Get-Command Get-Item -Syntax

Get-Item [-Path] <string[]> [-Filter <string>] [-Include <string[]>] [-Exclude <string[]>] [-Force] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-UseTransaction] [-Stream <string[]>] [<CommonParameters>]

Get-Item -LiteralPath <string[]> [-Filter <string>] [-Include <string[]>] [-Exclude <string[]>] [-Force] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-UseTransaction] [-Stream <string[]>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

- **Each output line** represents a **distinct *parameter set***.
- What parameters distinguish one parameters set from another isn't readily obvious; in this case, it is `-Path` vs. `-LiteralPath`, which is common for provider-related cmdlets.
- In a given parameter set, **any parameter that is *not* enclosed in `[...]` *as a whole*** (around *both* the parameter *name* (e.g., `-LiteralPath`) and the parameter *type* (e.g., `<string[]>`)) **is *mandatory***.

  - If **only the parameter *name* is enclosed in `[...]`** (e.g., `[-Path]`), the parameter is also **mandatory, but arguments may be specified *positionally*** - that is, you may *omit the parameter name* and specify just the *argument* (the value to bind to the parameter); e.g., instead of 
    `Get-Item -Path foo.txt` you may specify just 
    `Get-Item foo.txt`.

---

Based on the above, armed with the information as to:

- which parameter set you'll be using
- what its mandatory parameters are

you can then call your command in a manner that provides arguments to all mandatory parameters and thereby avoids interactive prompts.